# promise and getting response object as null using .then

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, angular-http

I'm getting json data trough web service

```
myService.getData()  
          .then(function(data, status, headers, config){ 
           alert(data.length);
    }...
```

Even though I'm able to get data and examine trough browser console inside code 
in `then` block I'm getting data as undefined.

What I'm doing wrong here?

Update:
my service call looks like this

```
 return $http.post("http:/...", {
                  headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==' }
              }).success(function(data, status, headers, config){ 
                  return data;
              }).error(function(data, status, headers, config){
                  alert('err');
              });
```

Comment: What does your service code look like? Are you returning a promise?

Comment: You aren't returning a promise from getData(), therefore you can't use the then method. Adjust your service to return the HTTP promise rather than the data.

Comment: You cannot `return` from a `success` callback. If you want to, use `.then` (although I don't see any reason for that callback here at all)

Answer (score 0):

the data you are passing to the resolve is an object and not an array.

objects do not have a length property, calling length on an object will give you undefined unless you have assigned a length property on it.

```
var arrayLike = ['a', 'b']
console.log(arrayLike.length)
//outputs: 2

var objectLike = { "a": 1, "b": 2 }
console.log(objectLike.length)
// outputs: undefined (no length property on the object, only a and b.
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that comes to mind is that 'data' object is an object that does not have length. If it should be string or array than maybe it is an object that has property of string or array. When debugging check where is data that your interested in and get it before using length property.

example:

```
data.myProperty.length
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this instead:

```
myService.getData()  
      .success(function(data, status, headers, config){ 
              alert(data.length);
          }).error(function(data, status, headers, config){
              alert('err');
          })...
```

this is your service:

```
return $http.post("http:/...", {
              headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic      QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==' }
          });
```

You need to return the promise made by $http.post()